# Hyperledger Fabric failure trying to do a peer channel update

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to do a channel update with the command:

```
peer channel update -c mychannel -f ./anchor_peer_tx_org1.pb -o orderer.example.com:7050
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing
update: error validating ReadSet: readset expected key
[Group]  /Channel/Application at version 1, but got version 2
```

I created the anchor_peer_tx_org1.pb using the following command:

```
configtxgen -outputAnchorPeersUpdate anchor_peer_tx_org1.pb -profile OneOrgChannel -asOrg Org1MSP -channelID mychannel
```

Anyone have any ideas what I am missing?

UPDATE:
Adding orderer logs. Nothing is logged on the peer when I attempt the channel update.

Orderer Logs:

```
2019-01-16 16:53:24.556 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 04e [channel: mychannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.26.0.6:54810 because of error: error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: readset expected key [Group]  /Channel/Applicatio
n at version 1, but got version 2
2019-01-16 16:53:24.558 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 04f streaming call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2019-01-16T16:53:24.552Z", "grpc.service": "orderer.AtomicBroadcast", "grpc.method": "Broadcast", "grpc.peer_address": "172.26.0.6:54810", "grpc.code": "OK", "grpc.call_durati
on": "6.1927ms"}
2019-01-16 16:53:24.571 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 050 Error reading from 172.26.0.6:54808: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-01-16 16:53:24.571 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 051 streaming call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2019-01-16T16:53:24.534Z", "grpc.service": "orderer.AtomicBroadcast", "grpc.method": "Deliver", "grpc.peer_address": "172.26.0.6:54808", "error": "rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled", "grpc.code": "Canceled", "grpc.call_duration": "37.3877ms"}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you signed the pb? Also can you attach the logs for the orderer and peers?

With that message error I think that it might be 2 things, the pb is not correctly formatted or that the pb is not signed by all parties, In my case I needed the orderer to sign the request.

I followed this tutorial and it worked for me: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html#prepare-the-cli-environment

Comment: I have signed the pb from both orgs. You say you had to get the orderer to sign the request, how did you do that exactly? I'm running "peer channel signconfigtx -f anchor_peer_tx_org1.pb -o orderer.example.com:7050" on each Orgs CLI.

Comment: What I had to do is to Impersonate the orderer admin from the CLI and then sign with it.